# PHP PSQL Insert Error

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to create a web interface for a baseball database but when I enter information into the forms and press submit it always gets to 'an error occurred'. 
Here's the webpage with the form.

```
<html>
<?php
$dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=mine user=mine password=mine");
if ($dbconn) {
    echo "Connection established <br/>";
}
echo "Here are the current NL West Teams <br/>";
$result = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT Name, Record FROM Teams");
if (!$result) {
    echo "An error occurred.\n";
    exit;
}
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Team: $row[0]  Record: $row[1]";
    echo "<br />\n";
}
?>

<form action="InsertPP.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Team: <input type="text" name="team"><br>
    Number: <input type="text" name="number"><br>
    Handed: <input type="text" name="Handed"><br>
    Position: <input type="text" name="Position"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>



</html>
```

And here is the Insert PHP script.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=mine user=mine password=mine");
if ($dbconn) {
    echo "Connection established <br/>";
}

$_first = $_POST["Handed"];
$_second = $_POST["Position"];
$_third = $_POST["name"];
$_fourth = $_POST["number"];
$_fifth = $_POST["team"];

$Query = pg_query(dbconn, "INSERT INTO PosPlayer VALUES('$_first', '$_second', '$_third', $_fourth, '$_fifth)'");
if (!$Query) {
    echo "An error occurred.\n";
    exit;
}
echo "Your Player has been added!";


?>

</body>
</html>
```

I input the same values into postgres and the forms, and the player was created directly in postgres, but some error occurred when input into the form. Any ideas?

EDIT: I fixed the missing $ in front of the dbconn. Still getting the 'An error occurred'.

Comment: You should use error reporting to diagnose errors. I'd start with `dbconn`missing the `$`. In here `pg_query(dbconn, ` <-- see it.. This code also is going to open you to SQL injections. I'm not familiar with `postgresql` but I imagine there is a driver that supports parameterized queries; I recommend using that.

Comment: This is a syntax error.

Comment: Check your web server's `error.log` file for the *actual* error message.

Comment: Please defer to the manual for your query function. `Warning
String interpolation of user-supplied data is extremely dangerous and is likely to lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. In most cases pg_query_params() should be preferred, passing user-supplied values as parameters rather than substituting them into the query string.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php This way quotes won't cause you issues with queries.

Answer (score 1):

Check the end of the `INSERT` statement. You have

```
'$_fifth)'"
```

where you should have

```
'$_fifth')"
```

i.e. the closing quote for the value should be *inside* the closing parenthesis, not outside it.

You really should be using a prepared statement for this instead of a dynamic query. The syntax would be something like this (using the PostgreSQL driver):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO PosPlayer VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)";
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "", $sql);
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "", array($_first, $_second, $_third, $_fourth, $_fifth));
```

This will automagically handle proper quoting, escaping and type-matching of the variables' values to prevent (among other things) possible SQL injection attacks. Note that `$1, $2,` &c. is the pg driver's syntax for bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`$Query = pg_query(dbconn, "INSERT INTO PosPlayer VALUES('$_first', '$_second', '$_third', $_fourth, '$_fifth)'");`

By

`$Query = pg_query($dbconn, "INSERT INTO PosPlayer VALUES('$_first', '$_second', '$_third', $_fourth, '$_fifth)'");`

**$** sign was missing from dbconn. Other than that, there seems to be nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Yikes...That should be reported back to me in my IDE right? I'm using PHPStorm and it didn't give me any errors...

Comment: Okay, I fixed that, but it still throws me the error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Enable the errors or use die() so that you can know the error. Does postgre uses die()?

Comment: @chris85 The error is that my query isn't going through. The code says that if there's something wrong with the query, then say "an error occurred". I'm not sure how else to quantify that. Is there someway to tell for sure where the error is occurring?

Comment: What are the columns in your database table?

Comment: @jkaw4 never seen ps driver docs in PHP manual before, pretty terrible. Do your inputs have `'`s in them?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys! I looked at it again, it looks like a ' was out of place and then it worked. Again, PHPStorm didn't catch this for me. Do you guys have another recommended IDE to use?

Comment: Cool! I'll look into it...I'm very new to PHP and Form handling in HTML. Thanks @AliZia.

Comment: No problem @jkaw4. :)